# Как сделать чтобы функция функции выдавала на консоль результат большими буквами

Tags: javascript

Надо чтобы слово автомобиль было большими буквами выдавало в консоль

```js
var texxt = "ауди <upcase>автомобиль</upcase> бмв <upcase>автомобиль</upcase>";

function sss(params) {
  var eee = texxt.replace(/\<upcase\>(\w*)\<\/upcase\>/g,
    function upcase(eee) {
      eee.toUpperCase();
    });
  return;

}
console.log(sss(texxt));
```

Здесь оно только заменяет а над UpperCase

```js
var texxt = "ауди <upcase>fsdfsd</upcase> бмв <upcase>fsdfsd</upcase>";

function sss(params) {
  var eee = texxt.replace(/\<upcase\>(\w*)\<\/upcase\>/g,
    " aaa"

  );
  return eee;

  function ddd(eee) {

    var qqq = eee.toUpperCase();
    return qqq;
  };

}
console.log(sss(texxt)); //выводит: ауди aaa бмв ааа , а надо ауди АВТОМОБИЛЬ бмв АВТОМОБИЛЬ
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```js
var texxt = "ауди <upcase>автомобиль</upcase> бмв <upcase>автомобиль</upcase>";

function sss(params) {
  text = params.replace(/<upcase>(.+?)<\/upcase>/g, function(match, contents){
    return contents.toUpperCase();
  });
  
  return text;
}

console.log(sss(texxt));
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: recile, `спасибо` конечно хорошо,  лучше принять ответ

Comment: @recile а можно вообще вместо "return text;" сразу выводить в консоль строкой "console.log(text);". Удачи!

Answer (score 5):

Решение уже было почти готово, что в первом варианте, что во втором.

В первом не хватает `return`, который возвращает значение переведенное в верхний регистр. А так же вместо полного совпадения, в верхний регистр нужно переводить только значение захваченное в первую группу. Оно передается вторым параметром в функцию. Кроме того `\w` не распознает русские буквы, поэтому его можно заменить на `[а-яё]`.

Если применить все выше сказанное первый пример примет вид:

```js
var texxt = "ауди <upcase>автомобиль</upcase> бмв <upcase>автомобиль</upcase>";

function sss(params) {
  var eee = texxt.replace(/\<upcase\>([а-яё]*)\<\/upcase\>/ig,
    function upcase(eee, $1) {
      return $1.toUpperCase();
    });
  return eee;

}
console.log(sss(texxt));
```

Если вернуться ко второму примеру, то определенная функция никуда не передается, поэтому и не применяется. Ее нужно передать вместо строки `"aaa"`. Плюс те же недочеты с группой и регулярным выражением

Если применить все выше сказанное второй пример примет вид:

```js
var texxt = "ауди <upcase>fsdfsd</upcase> бмв <upcase>fsdfsd</upcase>";

function sss(params) {
  var eee = texxt.replace(/\<upcase\>(\w*)\<\/upcase\>/g,
    ddd

  );
  return eee;

  function ddd(eee, $1) {

    var qqq = $1.toUpperCase();
    return qqq;
  };

}
console.log(sss(texxt)); //выводит: ауди aaa бмв ааа , а надо ауди АВТОМОБИЛЬ бмв АВТОМОБИЛЬ
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, F12:

```js
var str = 'Hello, World!';
  var style = [
   'text-transform: uppercase',
  ].join('');
  console.log('%c%s', style, str);
```

Comment: не работает, мне надо чтобы function  upcase(eee){
  eee.toUpperCase();
  }); ее подымала а она undefunded